# jQuery File Upload 'undefined' image url

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, file, upload

I'm using a plugin called [jQuery file upload](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) to upload images to a page.  Currently it uploads with the original image name as the file name (`IMG_1234`).  I need a specific format for the image name on the server (eg `1.123456.jpg`)

I found this PHP code that works for changing the image name:

```
class CustomUploadHandler extends UploadHandler
{
    protected function trim_file_name($name, $type) {
        $name = time()."_1";
        $name = parent::trim_file_name($name, $type);
        return $name;
    }
}
```

When I upload an image, it is named correctly, but the link for the image preview is `undefined`.  This prevents me from deleting the image via the plugin.

The variable `data.url` is `undefined`...  If I go back to the original code that doesn't rename the image, everything works fine.

Has anyone had any experience with this plugin that could help?  Thanks!

EDIT:

I've found part of the problem at least...the function to return the download link (which is also used for deletion) is giving the original file name, not the updated one.  I am really new to PHP classes, so I'm not sure where the variable originates and how to fix it.  I'd really appreciate any help I can get!

Here's the PHP code for that function:

```
protected function get_download_url($file_name, $version = null, $direct = false) {
    if (!$direct && $this->options['download_via_php']) {
        $url = $this->options['script_url']
            .$this->get_query_separator($this->options['script_url'])
            .'file='.rawurlencode($file_name);
            //  The `$file_name` variable is the original image name (`IMG_1234`), and not the renamed file.  
        if ($version) {
            $url .= '&version='.rawurlencode($version);
        }
        return $url.'&download=1';
    }
    if (empty($version)) {
        $version_path = '';
    } else {
        $version_url = @$this->options['image_versions'][$version]['upload_url'];
        if ($version_url) {
            return $version_url.$this->get_user_path().rawurlencode($file_name);
        }
        $version_path = rawurlencode($version).'/';
    }
    return $this->options['upload_url'].$this->get_user_path()
        .$version_path.rawurlencode($file_name);
}
```

EDIT 2:  I think it has something to do with `'param_name' => 'files',` in the options.  Anyone know what that does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by editing the `trim_file_name` function inside `UploadHandler.php` instead of extending the class in `index.php`.